# display a video corresponding to click of an item in list

Tags: html, onclick

I'm quite a newbie to HTML. I want to show a video on the click of an item (L1 and L2) in a frame.

I currently have this:

```
<div id="subjectlistdiv" , class="subjectlist">
    <ul id="buttons">
        <li id="LO1"><a href="#"></a> L1</li>
        <li id="LO2"><a href="#"></a> L2 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

css:

```
.subjectlist {
    position: absolute;
    margin - top: 5 px;
    margin - right: 300 px;
    left: 10 px;
    font - size: 18 px;
    border: 1 px solid black;
    border - width: relative;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to link to a video? Do you want a video to popup? I think we need a little more information on how you want this video to be displayed since you haven't yet incorporated it into your code.

Comment: I want to embed a youtube video in the popup that appears when I click the following list item and I can view the video in that popup.